# How to read from a file that was redirected

Tags: java, redirect

Sorry this is a simple question and I can't find what I'm looking for probably because I don't know what the keywords are.

For example I have a read.java that should be able to read how many A's there in a file called quotes.txt when I redirect the file:
    read < quotes.txt

How do I read from quotes.txt in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new Scanner(System.in)`. It will be available as Standard Input Stream for `read`, represented by [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), which is a [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

You can also do

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and use that `br`.